# How do I change PHP's date programmatically?

Tags: php, date

How do I change PHP's time-zone settings, programmatically, without configuring them in the php.ini

Comment: why do you want to change timezone settings on-the-fly? normally we should config it in php.ini

Comment: Even if there wasn't a dedicated function (and there is one), there's still [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set).

Comment: You could use it, in case your application works across borders, or if you have an international application, used by people from different countries.. For certain area's of the application you might want to set the timezone to their default time. Since your servers time might not be the same as theirs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is: `date_default_timezone_set();`
See the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Usage would be: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')`.